# static character array size at compile-time in c++

Tags: c++

I know this question asked many times and I'm not asking how to do it because i did that at compile-time. My question is how it works because that is what i don't understand.

When passing a `char[]` to a function it looses its information and become `char*` and because of that we can not get size of character array at compile time using template, so i tried and passed the string itself and it worked:

```
template <int N> inline int arr_len(const char (&)[N]) { return N - 1; }

#define STR "this is an example!"

const char *str_ptr = STR;

int main()
{
  int array_size = arr_len(STR);
}
```

I tested this code with VC++ 2008, Intel C++ 12 and GCC 4.7 and it works.

By passing the string itself the compiler sees it as `const char[]` - at least that what i think - and he able to get the string size, How is that possible?

Comment: There will be a different version of `arr_len` for every different size of array you use it with, and it just returns the length of the only type of array it can work with.

Comment: that's right but with optimization it will be the string length only.

Comment: Actually it has nothing to do with optimisation. This all happens at compile time.

Comment: This has been discussed a lot since 2004 (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/the1/archive/2004/05/07/128242.aspx) (from the middle of the text).

Comment: @SethCarnegie the template deduction will happened at compile-time but replacing the function call with the final value will occur only with optimisation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String literal type is an array, not a pointer. So, when you pass it directly to a function that takes array by reference, it doesn't decay to a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

That is because STR is a macro that is replaced before the compiler starts.

It replaces it with "XXXX" which is a string literal (not an array).

To get this to work do:

```
char const  str_ptr[] = "XXX YYY";
              //  ^^^^    Compiler works out size

int main()
{
    int array_size = arr_len(str_ptr);
                         //  ^^^^^^^ pass in an object that has a type.
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ when a function's parameter type is tentatively identified as an array, the parameter type is 'adjusted' to be a pointer to the array's element type.

So when you write: `void foo(char c[])` the compiler effectively rewrites it to be `void foo(char *c)`. Then when you pass an array:

```
char x[10];
foo(x);
```

C++ finds `void foo(char *c)` and sees that it can convert your `char []` argument into a `char *` and call the function, and this is exactly what it does.

However, this adjustment to the function's type only occurs when the written parameter type is an array. A reference to an array is not an array, so no equivalent adjustment is performed when you declare a function `void bar(char (&c)[10])`.

The second bit needed to answer your question is that the type of a string literal is an array of const char. When you write the string literal directly in the function call, with a function that takes `const char (&)[N]` C++ sees that it can pass a reference to the array instead of doing the "array -> pointer to first element" conversion. So that's what it does and the template type deduction finds the right number for the size of the string.